# button_to helper with nested tag inside

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

can a rails guru tell me how to use a `button_to` helper to generate this code:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="#"><i class="icon-shopping-cart icon-white"></i> Primary</a>
```

So far I have this, but I don't know how to nest the `i` tag inside:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="#"><i class="icon-shopping-cart icon-white"></i> Primary</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about `button_to`, but `link_to` can take a block of code which is used as the body of the `<a>` tag.

So if you created your button's like this, it should work:

```
<%= link_to your_link_path, class: "btn btn-primary" do %>
    <i class="icon-shopping-cart icon-white">Styled text.</i>
<% end %>
```

**EDIT**

Or using more Rails helpers:

```
    <%= link_to your_link_path, class: "btn btn-primary" do %>
        <%= content_tag :i, class: "icon-shopping-cart icon-white" do %>
          Primary
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: Why not style the links as buttons? It appears you're doing that anyway in your code example above.

Comment: I just tried <%= button_to "#{print '<i class="icon-shopping-cart icon-white">Add to Cart</i>'}", line_items_path(product_id: product),
        remote: true %> . I don't think that's what you meant when you said 'style'.  Looking into doing it with stylesheets. I'm using Twitter Bootstrap BTW.

Comment: No, what I meant was to create a style in your stylesheets which will give an anchor tag with a class like `anchor_button` the appearance of a button. I looked on the [Bootstrap Components page](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html) and saw that you can just add those bootstrap classes (`btn, btn-primary`) to an anchor tag. Those CSS classes are what is creating the button-like appearance, not the usage of `<button></button>`.

Comment: sweet, so the code in your edit looks promising. just saw it will try. thanks Zajn

Comment: Thanks, Zajn. That generated the correct code. Final code was: <%= link_to line_items_path(product_id: product), :class => "btn btn-primary", :remote => "true" do %>
        <%= content_tag :i, :class => "icon-shopping-cart icon-white" do %>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13007/discussion-between-david-west-and-zajn)

Answer (score 2):

## Solution 1

Using Rails 4.

button_to in Rails 4 can pass a block like link_to

## Solution 2

I build a gem called button_link_to.

Using the button_link_to method will generate button tag but without nested by form tag.

Just using it like link_to.

In your case:

```
<%= button_link_to link_path do %>
    <i class="icon-shopping-cart icon-white"></i> Primary
<% end %>
```

You can get more information from here: https://github.com/tonilin/button_link_to

If you want see a demo: http://button-link-to.herokuapp.com/